# Service for Google two step verfication

Tags: authentication

Google says:

"Why you shouldn’t use Google Voice to receive verification codes
If you use Google Voice to receive verification codes, you can easily create a situation where you’ve locked yourself out of your account.

For example, if you are signed out of your Google Voice app, you might need a verification code to get back in. However, you won’t be able to receive this verification code because it will be sent to your Google Voice, which you can’t access." (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185834?hl=en)

Then is there any message service that I can use for Google two step verification other than ones by telecom carriers (AT&T, Verizon, etc)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a security question at all.

Answer (score -1):

Mostly, I use the Google Authenticator App on my Smartphone as the primary means.

When necessary, it pops up and I tap the green checkmark to pass the 2FA part.

For account recovery I use Google Voice and have linked my phones (2 cellphones, one dumb and one smart, but both can receive texts) to Voice, so a text will go to both of them.

Then at Google I have set it to use an account at Yahoo as my alternate.  I never use it directly, and have it set to forward to my gmail, which, thanks to linking to Google Voice, makes it show up on both phones.

That way you can't ever lose control.